# Disallow directory contents, but Allow directory page in robots.txt

Tags: directory, block, robots.txt

Will this work for disallowing pages under a directory, but still allow a page on that directory url?

```
Allow: /special-offers/$
Disallow: /special-offers/
```

to allow:

www.mysite.com/special-offers/

but block:

www.mysite.com/special-offers/page1

www.mysite.com/special-offers/page2.html

etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked at Google's very own [robots.txt file](http://www.google.co.uk/robots.txt), they are doing exactly what I was questioning.

At line 136-137 they have:

```
Disallow: /places/
Allow: /places/$
```

So they are blocking any thing under places, but allowing the root places URL. The only difference with my syntax is the order, the `Disallow` being first.

Answer (score 1):

#### Standards

According to the [HTML 4.01 specification, Appendix B.4.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.4.1.1) the values allowed in `Disallow` (no pun intended) are partial URIs (representing partial or full paths), only:

> The "Disallow" field specifies a partial URI that is not to be visited. This can be a full path, or a partial path; any URI that starts with this value will not be retrieved. For example,
>
> **Disallow: /help** disallows both /help.html and /help/index.html, whereas
>
> **Disallow: /help/** would disallow /help/index.html but allow /help.html.

I don't think anything has changed since then, since current [HTML5 Specification Drafts](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/) don't mention `robots.txt` at all.

#### Extensions

However, in practice, many Robot Engines (such as [Googlebot](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449&from=35237&rd=1)) are more flexible in what they accept. If you use, for instance:

```
Disallow: /*.gif$
```

then Googlebot will skip any file with the `gif` extension. I think you could do something like this to disallow all files under a folder, but I'm not 100% sure (you could test them with [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/robots-analysis)):

```
Disallow: /special-offers/*.*$
```

#### Other options

Anyway, you shouldn't rely on this too much (since each search engine might behave differently), so if possible it would be preferrable to use [meta tags or HTTP headers](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?hl=pt-BR) instead. For instance, you could configure your webserver to include this header in all responses that should not be indexed (or followed):

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow
```

Search for the best way of doing it in your particular webserver. Here's [an example](http://www.kahunaburger.com/2012/05/18/mod_rewrite-and-mod_headers-to-rewrite-headers/) in Apache, combining [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) with [`mod_headers`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html) to conditionally set some headers depending on the URL pattern. Disclaimer: I haven't tested it myself, so I can't tell how well it works.

```
# all /special-offers/ sub-urls set env var ROBOTS=none
RewriteRule ^/special-offers/.+$ - [E=ROBOTS:none]

# if env var ROBOTS is set then create header X-Robots-Tag: $ENV{ROBOTS}
RequestHeader set X-Robots-Tag %{ROBOTS}e env=ROBOTS
```

(Note: `none` is equivalent to `noindex, nofollow`)